# What is the correct method of injecting jquery dependency into a javascript class and accessing the class instance object in events callback?

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, dependency-injection, callback

I am looking for the correct way to implement a javascript class without using a specific framework (react, angular and ...), jQuery dependency injection and access the instance object in the class methods (using the this keyword) when assigning callbacks to events.

The implementation I did is as follows:

**Parent class:**

```
import autoBind from "./auto-bind.js";

class Tools {
    constructor() {
        autoBind(this);
    }

    init() { }
}

export default Tools;
```

**Sub class:**

```
import autoBind from "./auto-bind.js";
import Tools from "./tools.js"
import * as hub from "./hub.js"

class PanelTools extends Tools {
    constructor() {
        super();

        autoBind(this);
    }

    async init() {
        let _this = this;

        super.init();

        await hub.start();

        $(document)
            .ajaxStart(function () {
                _this.showLoader();
            });
    }

    showLoader() {
        $("#loader").show();
    }
}
```

- It should be noted that I am not using a special framework (react,
  angular and ...) here.
- I used the "auto-bind" library to bind `this`.
- I implemented the `async init()` method to call await functions.
- I defined the variable `_this` in the class methods to access the
  instance.

Is it correct to implement these classes and use jquery in the methods?

Comment: If it works for you, then it's correct. Voting to close as opinion-based.

Comment: True, but it would be good if I could know the correct structure of this class and how to correctly inject the jQuery dependency. @InSync